# I'm trying to change the menu css style while hovering one specific child of the menu. Not familiar with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, tumblr

jQuery seems like the way to go, so maybe you guys can tell me how to implement what I want. I'm creating a drop down menu for a tumblr website. I'm almost done by now, but: Tumblr post don't go down when the dropdown menu expands, in fact my menu sticks behind the post even with z-axis=1. The solution was easy, if hover on the whole menu, add some margin below the menu, but that also happens when I hover on a child of the menu that has not childs. 
To make it better looking, **I want to add the margin on the whole menu, just when hovering the child that has childs** (class="aboutus"). This cannot be done by CSS, I know, but have almost no idea of jQuery. I'm guessing it might not be difficult, but...

I'm not an expert on this, in fact I started learning about html and css like 2 weeks ago, so any help is appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/correocaminos">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="aboutus">
            <a href="/aboutus">SOBRE NOSOTROS&nbsp;<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="/asociacioncultural">ASOCIACIÓN CULTURAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="/equipo">EQUIPO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/revista">LA REVISTA</a></li>
        <li><a href="/unete">ÚNETE</a></li>
        <li class="issuu"><a href="https://issuu.com/correocacultural">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.clearfix:after {
display:block;
clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:{TitleColor};
}

.menu {
    width:100%;

}

.menu:hover {
    margin:0 0 70px 0;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0 auto;
    list-style:none;
    font-family: {TitleFont}, "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: {TitleFontWeight};
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color: {AccentColor};
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu .arrow {
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:0%;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:{AccentColor};
    color: {TitleColor};
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:120%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:26px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:{TitleColor};
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:{AccentColor};
    color: {TitleColor};
}
.twitter {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/g5BqVFr.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 8px;
}
.menu > ul > .twitter:hover > a {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/1IVH284.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 8px;
}
.issuu {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/NsM9xT2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 8px;
}
.menu > ul > .issuu:hover > a {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/kbGIHN4.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 8px;
}
```

EDIT: The webpage is the following: http://correocaminos.tumblr.com

```css
    .clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
 
/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:{TitleColor};
}
 
.menu {
    width:100%;
    
}

.menu:hover {
    margin:0 0 70px 0;
}
 
.menu li {
    margin:0 auto;
    list-style:none;
    font-family: {TitleFont}, "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: {TitleFontWeight};
}
 
.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color: {AccentColor};
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
.menu .arrow {
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:0%;
}
 
/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
 
.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
 
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:{AccentColor};
    color: {TitleColor};
}
 
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}
 
.sub-menu {
    width:120%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:26px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:{TitleColor};
}
 
.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
}
 
.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:block;
}
 
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:{AccentColor};
    color: {TitleColor};
}
.twitter {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/g5BqVFr.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 8px;
}
.menu > ul > .twitter:hover > a {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/1IVH284.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 8px;
}
.issuu {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/NsM9xT2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 8px;
}
.menu > ul > .issuu:hover > a {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/kbGIHN4.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/correocaminos">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li class="aboutus">
                <a href="/aboutus">SOBRE NOSOTROS&nbsp;<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
 
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="/asociacioncultural">ASOCIACIÓN CULTURAL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/equipo">EQUIPO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/revista">LA REVISTA</a></li>
            <li><a href="/unete">ÚNETE</a></li>
            <li class="issuu"><a href="https://issuu.com/correocacultural">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Put it in a fiddle/codepen so we can see a working example pls.

Comment: Done. It's the first time I comment on StackOverflow so don't really know if that is what you're asking. Also, the colors in the code are referred to tumblr inputs, so to see a fully working example you can go to the website.

Answer (score 0):

I have change some css

```
.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
  content:'';
  display: table;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:120%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:46px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:{TitleColor};
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rejhz9fv/2/